# Expression tree from IronPython

Tags: linq, ironpython, expression-trees

I use this code to execute a python expression using IronPython.

```
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();      
    scope.SetVariable("m", mobject);
    string code = "m.ID > 5 and m.ID < 10";
    ScriptSource source = 
engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(code, SourceCodeKind.Expression);
    source.Execute(scope);
```

Is there a way to get the produced Expression Tree as c# object, e.g. the `BlockExpression`
?

Comment: Where are you passing in the code?

Comment: I have referenced Microsoft Scripting libraries and IronPython. Iam using .net 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IronPython's internal ASTs also happen to be Expression trees, so you just need to get the AST for your code, which you can do using the [`IronPython.Compiler.Parser`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Compiler/Parser.cs) class. The Parser.ParseFile method will return a [`IronPython.Compiler.Ast.PythonAst`](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Compiler/Ast/PythonAst.cs) instance representing the code.

Using the parser is a bit tricky, but you can look at the [`BuildAst` method](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Modules/_ast.cs#L64) of the _ast module for some hints. Basically, it's:

```
Parser parser = Parser.CreateParser(
    new CompilerContext(sourceUnit, opts, ThrowingErrorSink.Default),
    (PythonOptions)context.LanguageContext.Options);

PythonAst ast = parser.ParseFile(true);
```

`ThrowingErrorSink` also comes from the `_ast` module. You can get a `SourceUnit` instance like so (c.f. [`compile` builtin](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/blob/master/Languages/IronPython/IronPython/Modules/Builtin.cs#L281)):

```
SourceUnit sourceUnit = context.LanguageContext.CreateSnippet(source, filename, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
```

You then have to walk the AST to get useful information out of it, but they should be similar (but not identical to) C# expression trees.

Comment: What is `context` here?

Comment: @Asad: a CodeContext instance. I believe you can also get a LanguageContext instance from the ScriptEngine.